# SQL Error says every derived table must have alias

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use this query

```
select s.* from ta as s left join (select a.* from tb as a)
```

This error appears

> every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: fully address answer @Sebastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an alias after parenthesis as below

```
select s.* 
from ta as s 
left join (select a.* from tb as a) as a on/* here you need input condtion */
```

Comment: c , What Mean ? @Parado

Comment: @RafatHajAli  Where is c?

Comment: I have an error in SQL syntax

Comment: @RafatHajAli I don't have `c` in my query :)

Comment: Ok c disappear but now i have an error in sql syntax , what is that error

Comment: @RafatHajAli Can you show me that error? Try to run my query again - I added `as` before `a`, maybe this will solve the problem

Comment: No , Error Still Apperar
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: @Parado: Error must be `"join condition missing"`

Comment: need ON s.someting=s.something

Comment: @Ravinder I though that but I think it's not complete OP's query

Comment: @RafatHajAli Is it your full query?

Comment: Yes , Success 
Thank You @Parado